# Parse XML search results page with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

#### Background:

I am trying to include Google search results in a page that I am creating. These search results are formatted as [XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML).

At the moment I am importing the XML like this:

```javascript
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // Code for Internet Explorer7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, and Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else {
    // Code for Internet Explorer 6 and Internet Explorer 5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", "foo", false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
```

Where `foo` is the [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) of the XML file holding the search results.

#### Problem:

This works perfectly, but only when `foo` ends in a proper extension such as `.xml`. This poses a problem, because the page that contains the search results (`http://search.domain.com/search?q=queryString&output=xml`) has no extension.

When I try to call `xmlhttp.open()` using the URL of the search results, `xmlhttp.send()`fails and any functions or commands that follow it are not executed.

I have tried several different methods of importing/parsing the file using [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) and plain JavaScript, but none of them seem to work.

#### Questions:

Is there a way to import only the text of the extension-less file?
I would then be able to parse the text using `parseFromString`. This would allow me to get the data I need, but only by copying all the text from the search results (no matter the amount) into my page.

I would prefer if there were a method that would allow me to open and parse the extension-less page as an XML file.

Let me know if you need any more information.

---

This is the code that should be returned:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE GSP SYSTEM "google.dtd">
<GSP VER="3.2">
  <TM>TimeTaken(in seconds)</TM>
  <Q>queryString</Q>
  <PARAM name="q" value="queryString" original_value="queryString"/>
  <PARAM name="output" value="xml" original_value="xml"/>
  <PARAM name="ie" value="UTF-8" original_value="UTF-8"/>
  <PARAM name="ulang" value="en" original_value="en"/>
  <PARAM name="ip" value="ipAddress" original_value="ipAddress"/>
  <PARAM name="access" value="p" original_value="p"/>
  <PARAM name="sort" value="date:D:L:d1" original_value="date:D:L:d1"/>
  <RES SN="1" EN="10">
    <M><!-- The estimated total number of results for the search -->3560</M>
    <FI/>
    <NB>
      <NU>/search?q=queryString&amp;lr=&amp;ie=UTF-8&amp;output=xml&amp;access=p&amp;sort=date:D:L:d1&amp;start=10&amp;sa=N</NU>
    </NB>
    <!-- First result -->
    <R N="1"> <U><!--URL of result-->http://www.google.com?option=42</U>
      <UE><!--URL of result with special characters changed to html
              equivalent-->http://www.google.com%3Foption%3D</UE>
      <T><!--Title of result -->Google </T>
      <RK><!--Query Ranking
              10(highest relevance)-1(lowest relevance)-->10</RK>
      <ENT_SOURCE> <!--Identifies the application ID (serial number) of the
                      search appliance that contributes to a result.-->
        S5-KUB000F0ADETLA </ENT_SOURCE>
      <FS NAME="date" VALUE=""/>
      <S><!-- Snippet for the search result --> Search the world's information,
      including webpages, images, videos and more. <em>Google</em> has many
      special features to help you find exactly what you're looking&nbsp;
      <b>...</b></S><LANG>en</LANG>
      <HAS><!--special features that are included for this search result-->
        <L/>
        <C SZ="30k" CID="TiXnj_p8qlgJ" ENC="ISO-8859-1"/>
      </HAS>
    </R>
  </RES>
</GSP>
```

Now that I actually take a good look at it, the XML code that Google promised me when using `&output=xml` isn't looking so "xml-ey". Is there a way around that, or will I have to scrap my project?

I was able to get this same "XML" to work nicely with a php parser, but I was asked to change everything to JavaScript instead of [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery), simply use its **[.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)** method which can automatically parse XML when the dataType option is set to "xml".

```
jQuery.ajax({
   url:"http://example.com/someurl",
   dataType:"xml",
   success:function(xml) {
      //xml will be an object which you can use to access the elements.
   }
});
```

If the content-type of the file being retrieved is being sent as for instance `text/html`, you can change `dataType` to `'text xml'` so that jQuery knows to view the text as XML.

If however you want to keep using vanilla JavaScript to do the [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) requests you will have to get the `.responseText` instead of the `.responseXML` and then parse

```
var xmlDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xmlhttp.responseText,'text/xml');
```

Note that DOMParser isn't fully supported, Internet Explorer below 9, for instance, does not support it.

Comment: Neither of these solutions seems to work for me.  My problem seems to be in the `send` or `success`.  These occur and nothing happens after that.  I am trying to alert characters or variables in order to check whether I have made it to a certain point.  But, these alerts never happen after a `send` or within a `success`.

Comment: @Enigmadan you are probably getting an error, you can set an error callback just like you set the success callback. More than likely thexml you are trying to get is not valid XML which would cause the success function to not be called

Comment: That appears to be the case. Would it be possible to interpret "pseudo-xml"?  I guess I trusted google to format search results correctly based on their documentation...

Comment: @Enigmadan can you edit your question to contain a sample of the data that is returned by google

Comment: I added a sample search result.